# How to serve different Angular locales during development using ng serve?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I'm developing an app in two different languages (fa/en) using [Angular Internationalization (i18n)](https://angular.io/guide/i18n).

- The target is to deploy the two different builds into sub-folders on the server (example.com/en/...)
- These builds are different not only in translation but also styles and layout directions are different.

I can serve any of the localization (languages) like this

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      ...
      ,
      "configurations": {
      ...
        },
        "fa": {
          "localize": ["fa"],
          "baseHref": "/fa/"
        },
        "en": {
          "localize": ["en"],
          "baseHref": "/en/"
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
        },
        "en": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:en"
        },
        "fa": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:fa"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build"
      }
    },
    ...
  }
```

And then `ng serve --configuration=en` works and I have it on `http://localhost:4200/en/...` But **I need to serve both languages simultaneously** during development to work on the styles and the correct layout and check the translations. If I try to do this in the build configuration `"localize": ["fa","en"]` I get the following error.

`An unhandled exception occurred: The development server only supports localizing a single locale per build`

The best I got so far is to run `ng serve ..` multiple times on different ports to have two instances of the development server in different locales but that is kinda ugly. I am hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 31):

In Angular 9 the development server (ng serve) can only be used with a single locale.

However, you can still serve each locale on different ports by running two separate commands:

`ng serve --configuration=fa --port 4200`

`ng serve --configuration=en --port 4201`

Hopefully, they will introduce multiple locale options for development builds in Angular 10

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm currently doing as stated in my question on the last paragraph. Hopefully they will fix this soon enough.

Comment: its angular 12 still no fix :D

Comment: They should support it show more people will use native way instead of 3rd party.

Comment: Aside from running `ng serve` for each language (each on different port), you can also set up http proxy for each locale, so that all language versions are accessible on a single localhost port.

Comment: Angular is @ v16, and still no fix!
This is a good day wasted on this. :"(

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to quickly validate the localization for a specific language, like me, just add `"localize": ["<YOUR-LOCALE>"]` to the `angular.json` in `"projects" > "<YOUR PROJECT NAME>" > "architect" > "build" > "configurations" > "development"`. After that, the normal `ng serve` command uses the specified localization. Once you're done, don't forget to remove it again ;)

And yes, I'm aware that this doesn't address the question, but this thread shows up at the very top in google.

Answer (score 0):

`ng serve` can provide only one locale at a time because of the nature angular is handling i18n

in addition to answer from Elias another workaround for run multiple languages on localhost is to serve the built locally

ie. run with http-server

1. `npm install http-server -g`
2. build the app with all locales
3. http-server dist/apps/my-app/browser (i use nx, path is different on plain angular)

then one can call [http://127.0.0.1:8081/[LOCALE]](http://127.0.0.1:8081/%5BLOCALE%5D)

Comment: OK, but that's not `ng serve`, as the question requires.