# Change localize-code (language) for angular in configuration

Tags: angular, testing, localization

I prepared my angular application for localizing. I want to test the different languages before publishing.

```
{  
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myProject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en-US",
        "locales": {
          "de-CH": "messages.de-CH.xlf"
        }
      },
...
```

*Csaba* mentions here, this can be achieved by using different configurations. But I can't find the configuration-key to apply the local-id.
[How to serve different Angular locales during development using ng serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683954/how-to-serve-different-angular-locales-during-development-using-ng-serve)

There's only a "localize" true/false

```
"development": {
  "buildOptimizer": false,
  "optimization": false,
  "vendorChunk": true,
  "extractLicenses": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "namedChunks": true,
  "localize":true
}
```

Any ideas how testing a different local can be achieved?

Comment: I found some help here: https://youtu.be/88hE8_M53SA?t=720

Answer (score 0):

**For deployment ...**

As it seems the option localize `true`/`false` controls whether `ng build`  will generate localized version of the application in `dist`-folder.

if `true` dist will have one subfolder per localization defined in section `locales`

**For development ...**

This worke for me...

[image]